# Formatting issues with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm trying to get this output through `biblatex`,

> “Prospects of Slavery Expansion,” Charleston Mercury.  In The Causes of the Civil War, edited by Kenneth Stampp, 148-49.  New York: Touchstone, 1991.

The problem is there is no author, it goes title of article in book / the source from a newspaper / book / editor / page number so on.

`@misc` just seems to garble it all up, it's supposed to be in Chicago style like this reference.

I should add I'm just looking for the `.bib` entry, I looked through the wiki book guide and I couldn't find a solution.

These are the packages I'm using for the Chicago style:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate, notes ,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

I've been mucking around with the `.bib` entry, I honestly don't know how to approach it but this is the non-functional entry so far:

```
@misc{mercury,
title = "Prospects of Slavery Expansion",
volume = "Charleston Mercury",
booktitle     = "The Causes of the Civil War",
date = "1991",
publisher    = "Touchstone",
editor           = "Kenneth Stampp",
location       = "New York",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the full bib entry that's giving you trouble, and please state exactly which bibliography style you use -- there are quite a few `bst` files that claim to implement "Chicago-style" formatting.

Comment: If your snippet says the truth the title of your question and the tag is wrong as you are using *biblatex* and *biber* and not *bibtex*.

Comment: Ok, tags and title are fixed

Comment: I'm pretty sure `@misc` is the wrong entry type here, but I'm certain you can't (and shouldn't) use `authordate` for any style where the year is meant to come at the end of the entry: that's the traditional Chicago 'notes and bibliography' (option `notes`) style. But I think you want to look at the `@inbook` entry type ... though I don't understand how something has a "title of article in book / the source from a newspaper".

Comment: Imho you have two bib entries here: The newspaper (@article) and the book with the reprint. In standard biblatex I would use the `related` field, but biblatex-chicago doesn't seem to use it, so you will probably have to play around with xref, crossref, userf or reprinttitle or add the book information through the note field.

Comment: @ jon What it's supposed to be is a reference of an article named "Prospects of Slavery Expansion" which appeared in the "Charleston Mercury". This article is sourced from a book named "The Causes of the Civil War"

Comment: Hmm, in my opinion, then, if you've only looked at the article (yourself, directly), then you should only cite the article in the sense that it's what should appear in the bibliography. An explanatory aside in the relevant footnote can explain the relationship to the original source (which doesn't need to be cited: surely the article explains how to find the original source). Otherwise, you're going to need to create two entries and link them via `crossref` or `xref`.

Comment: If you have found a solution it is in no way frowned upon to add the solution as an answer yourself (in fact, it is encouraged). We want to keep the question and answer spaces separated, so we do not answer questions in an edit, but with a separate answer.

Comment: @jon - I've provided an answer in which `{{Charleston Mercury}}` is assigned to the `author` field. The double curly braces ensure that it will be interpreted as a "corporate" author.

Answer (score 2):

You state that this entry has no author. However, functionally speaking, "Charleston Mercury" *is* the author of the piece. Since it's a "corporate author", the field should be

```
author = {{Charleston Mercury}},
```

(note the *double* curly braces) to assure that the entry will not be (mis)interpreted as having been written by a person whose first name was "Charleston" and surname was "Mercury".

If you wanted to adopt the convention of italicizing the second part of the newspaper's name ("New Orleans *Bee*" "Chicago *Tribune*", etc), you'd write

```
author = {{Charleston \emph{Mercury}}},
```

Incidentally, it might be helpful to provide the salient information for the `chapter` and `pages` fields of this publication as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{newbibl.bib}
@incollection{mercury,
   author = {{Charleston Mercury}},
   title  = {Prospects of Slavery Expansion},
   chapter   = {50},
   pages     = {148--149},
   booktitle = {The Causes of the Civil War},
   date      = {1991},
   publisher = {Touchstone},
   editor    = {Kenneth Stampp},
   location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate, notes ,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{newbibl}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a pretty rough and ready solution for this

Thanks to everyone for the assistance

I've basically switched around the title and author fields of the .bib file and added formatting changes where necessary, here is the .bib

```
@incollection{mercury,
title = {Charleston Mercury},
author = {{\enquote{Prospects of Slavery Expansion}\nopunct }},
booktitle     = {The Causes of the Civil War},
date = {1991},
publisher    = {Touchstone},
editor           = {Kenneth Stampp},
location       = {New York},
options       = {useeditor=false},
}
```

and in the .tex I removed quotation marks around the title (as it's pulled a switcheroo with the author field)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{#1}
```

this wont work if I wanted more incollection references but as that isn't a problem for this document thats fine for now.

Regards